# Ускорение алгоритма поиска пересечений в игре

Tags: c++, алгоритм, разработка-игр, оптимизация

У меня есть 2D игра, в которой есть игроки и противники. Каждый может стрелять множеством пуль. На данный момент для проверки пересечений Entity (это любой рисуемый объект: игрок, враг, пуля) проверяется пересечение каждого с каждым. События пересечения обрабатываются по-разному (игрок+пуля=-хп, пуля+пуля=-пули и так далее). В итоге игра начинает лагать, когда на экране много врагов и у игрока баф на количество пуль. **Какие алгоритмы можно применить для более быстрой проверки пересечений?**

Игрок: мало - 1 или 2; враги: много, но не больше пары десятков; пули: очень много, но не больше тысячи, есть разные типы пуль.

Игра написана на C++. Проверено, что замедляет программу именно это место.

Comment: А как вы сейчас проверяете?

Comment: @timur я же написал - каждый Entity с каждым другим. Проверяю пересечение хитбоксов просто

Comment: Ну это теоретическое описание не даёт нам понятия, как вы всё таки вычисляете пересечение, но другой вопрос, если у вас это выполняется последовательно, может попробовать распараллелить?

Comment: @Komdosh как обычное пересечение N*N прямоугольников. Да, последовательно. А как распараллелить?

Comment: ну комментарий к тому, что нам бы код, можете обезличить

Comment: Ни какой волшебной пули (без каламбуров) здесь скорей всего не будет. Нужно как-то сокращать перебор. Как именно без конкретики не скажешь... Первое что приходит на ум — разбить сцену на области заведомо меньше, чем размеры сущностей и проверять для каждой столкновения только с объектами в соседних областях. Ещё я где-то читал, что пули в полёте редко сталкиваются, так что можно, например, просто отказаться от проверки столкновения «пуль» (или некоторых их типов) друг с другом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, я вот тоже думал над чем-то таким. Типа разбить экран на квадраты и хотя бы пересечение пуль не проверять из далёких квадратов. Вопрос, как поддерживать свойство "в каком квадрате сейчас Entity" правильно...

Comment: Это ищется по сочетанию spatial query. Идея с делением на квадраты - spatial partitioning. По ним строят spatial tree или spatial hash. Можете взять что-нить готовое, тот де box2d.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, почитаю

Comment: Стандартный способ - разбиваете "карту" на "сектора". Каждый объект привязывается к одному или нескольким секторам.  При передвижении объекта, переводите его между секторами в зависимости от положения и размера. Коллизии проверяете только для объектов, попадающих в один и тот же сектор.

Comment: @Mark, присоединяюсь к тому, что написали более грамотные люди...

Answer (score 10):

К сожалению, Вы не предоставили информации ни по архитектуре игры, ни по её жанру, поэтому придётся предполагать `:)` Жанр скорее всего Top-Down Shooter, архитектура, судя по комментариям, примерно следующая:

[image: Предположительная архитектура, набросок UML диаграммы классов]

Один из вариантов оптимизации стрельбы – реализовать её как отдельную игровую сущность, а не как разновидность обычных объектов с полноценной физикой:

[image: Улучшенная архитектура, набросок UML диаграммы классов]

Как минимум, это позволит убрать лишние проверки столкновения пуль друг с другом. Также, проверку столкновения со статическими объектами (ландшафт, деревья, стены) можно проводить реже, только в момент выстрела. Более того, во многих играх скорость выстрела считается большой и даже проверки столкновения с юнитами со всеми вытекающими для них последствиями происходят лишь в момент выстрела, и следом создаётся спец.эффект со светом, взрывом, магией и т.п, а собственно объектов пуль как таковых в коде игры нет в принципе.

Если же Ваши пули, снаряды летят с относительно небольшой скоростью, то их проверку столкновений с юнитами всё равно можно проводить раз в N шагов. А если снаряд летит по воздуху (например, выстрел гранатомёта) то расчёты достаточно проводить всего дважды – в момент выстрела построить траекторию с учётом статических объектов, и в момент падения проверять столкновения с юнитами для нанесения урона.

Также в комментариях упоминали про разделение игрового поля на части и их независимую обработку. Этот приём называется зонирование (zoning) и довольно часто применяется в ГеймДеве будучи полезным и важным как для дизайнеров, так и для разработчиков, т.к позволяет значительно оптимизировать и игровую физику, и графический рендер – например, это актуально для сцен с качественными зеркальными эффектами, т.к это очень ресурсозатратный процесс, особенно в старых играх. И в целом, в истории игровой индустрии полно примеров компромиссов дизайнеров и разработчиков, важно смотреть сразу с обеих сторон.

---

Ещё несколько советов:

1. В вопросе по оптимизации кода старайтесь приводить или сам код, алгоритмы, или архитектуру, например, используя [UML диаграммы классов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2), хотя бы в урезанном виде, как выше сделал я.
2. В вопросах по ГеймДеву стоит описывать жанр и желаемое поведение, т.к нередко его можно достичь совсем другими способами. Впрочем, это касается не только гейм.дева.
3. Учите английский и не брезгайте пользоваться, искать ответы в более тематических сайтах, например, на [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Столько текста, а непосредственно по существу только упоминание в конце, что в комментариях уже дали ответ...

Comment: @user7860670 если у вас трудности с извлечением полезной информации из текста, то могу только посочувствовать `(:` Я здесь всё же не абстрактно в воздух размышлял, а привёл полезную информацию из разностороннего _практического_ опыта в геймдеве.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое что можно предложить это реализовать пулю как луч ( если конечно у вас пули не меняют направление в зависимости от ситуаций, тогда можно предоставить пулю как сущность с своим BBox и уже проверять пересечение с ним ), а все объекты поместить в октарное дерево и соотвественно проверять через него пересечение луча ( или BBox пули ) и дерева, таким образом вы отсечете ненужные проверки, так же как уже упоминалось в ответе выше стоит разделить на зоны, чтобы избежать 100% ненужных проверок

октарное дерево конечно очень сильно завязано на количестве перемещений объектов, если у вас сильно динамическая сцена, то перемещение объектов по узлам может создавать свою нагрузку и тогда нужно смотреть в сторону других алгоритмов для динамических объектов, статику к примеру все так же можно упаковать в октарное дерево, что даст точно прирост скорости проверки

А вообще я думаю вам стоит зарегистрироваться на gamedev.ru и искать подобную информацию там, там весьма часто всплывают подобные вопросы и в зависимости от сеттинга дают действительно оптимизированные решения, возможно в вашем сеттинге можно сделать в разы быстрее чем предложенный мной вариант